# How to check if all possible combination of elements in an array grouped together has been covered in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Assume that I have the following array:

```
const_val_ary[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Based on the above array, I group the elements in a way that each group should have at least one element and upto **const_val_ary.size**. The number of groups is generated randomly and is limited between 1 to **const_val_ary.size**. Each element must appear in only one group. So for instance [[1,2,3],4,5,6] is a valid output but [[1,2,3],3,4,5] is not (3 appeared twice and 6 is not in any group) . I want to know how can I cover all the possible combination?

EDIT: Here is the code that I am working on:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/56Lu

Comment: Can you explain more about the "groups"? is the group size 3 or another random number? There must be a limit to the number of groups= const_val_ary.size/groups.size. And by "cover", do you mean function coverage, or do you mean what randomization can produce and you are looking for constraints?

Comment: Yes you are right I didn't mentioned that the number of groups is limited between 1 to const_val_ary.size. 
I am actually stuck at both cases! I wrote couple of constraints to produce the groups but for functional coverage I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Can you show an example of the data you want to create and then cover.

Comment: Ex:   [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]   ---> 4 groups
Ex:   [1,[2,3,4],[5,6]]   ---> 3 groups
Ex:   [[1,2,3,4],5],6]    ---> 2 groups
Ex:   [1,2,3,4,5,6]       ---> 6 groups

and I want to cover all these combinations

Comment: Can you update your question and show that as a variable declaration with a set of assignment or randomizations. How did you write the constraints?

Comment: I added a link to edaplayground project

Comment: Your code has little relationship to what you appear to be asking. Why is there no `const_val_ary`? And where did `chs_per_grp.sum() == 6` come from?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution.

```
int original_data[$], group[$];

// Fill the original_data queue with your list

original_data.unique();
while (original_data.size() != 0)
begin
  group.push_front(original_data.pop_front);
  original_daata.shuffle();
end
```